# How can I add a scrollbar to a newly appeared canvas after clicking a button in Tkinter using Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**Python. Tkinter.**
I want to make this: After clicking on a button, little Canvas(or another widget that can be overlaid with other widgets) should appear with many rows-buttons and with Scrollbar. *Code Based on youtube-video Codemy.com - Adding a Full Screen ScrollBar*

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def func(event):
    right_frame = Canvas(root, height=323, width=147, bg='#bec4da')
    right_frame.place(x=250, y=35)

    my_scrollbar = Scrollbar(right_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=right_frame.yview)
    right_frame.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
    right_frame.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: right_frame.configure(scrollregion=right_frame.bbox('all')))
    my_scrollbar.place(x=133, y=1, height=323)

    second_frame = Frame(right_frame, width=100, height=100, bg='#bec4da')

    right_frame.create_window((0, 0), window=second_frame, anchor='nw')

    for i in range(26):
        btn = Button(second_frame, text=i+10)
        btn.pack()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
btn = Button(text = 'command' )
btn.bind('<Button-1>', func)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But Scrollbar is unavailable. When I added Scrollbar without fun() everything works.[doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdxpY.png)

Comment: You have to set the scrollregion for the Canvas to have any idea that it needs a scrollbar (currently, you're only doing this in response to a `<Configure>` event), and you have to do a `.update_idletasks()` first so that the Frame being displayed by the Canvas can calculate how tall it needs to be to hold all the Buttons.

Comment: It is better to create the scrollbar and the canvas as children of a frame instead.  Also bind `<Configure>` event to `second_frame` instead of `right_frame` (the canvas).